# Celery 4 + Django + Redis, missing django settings section in documentation?

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to setup celery 4 in my Django project which I want Redis as broker. But I cannot find Django specific settings for broker in the Celery 4 [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)? Also the [settings documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html) for version 4 does not mention about `CELERY_BROKER_URL` anymore, I am sure the version 3 documentation does mention these settings.

I searched on the web and found these settings:

```py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

But I am not sure if it's for version 3 or version 4. I am utterly confused.

Answer (score 0):

OK! Found paragraph buried inside of the "[First steps with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)" documentation:

> The uppercase name-space means that all Celery configuration options must be specified in uppercase instead of lowercase, and start with CELERY_, so for example the task_always_eager setting becomes CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER, and the broker_url setting becomes CELERY_BROKER_URL. This also applies to the workers settings, for instance, the worker_concurrency setting becomes CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY.